# ClassBaseView Create Form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have simple model:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30);
```

Form:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title=forms.CharField()
```

And class in view:

```
class TescCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'test.html'
    forms=TestForm
    success_url = ''

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return redirect('')
```

But i have erros:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test'
```

Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 106, in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 36, in get_object
    queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 844, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1263, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1225, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1096, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 70, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\triest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 965, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test'
[08/Oct/2018 21:46:08] "GET /articles/test HTTP/1.1" 500 124900
```

Routs:

```
app_name='articles'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',ArticleListView.as_view(),name="list"),
    path('<pk>',views.DetailView.as_view(),name="detail"),
    path('create',ArticleCreateView.as_view(),name="create"),
    path('test',TescCreateView.as_view(),name="test"),
    path('create2', views.article_create, name="create2"),
]
```

Comment: Please include a full traceback. The exception is not caused here. This is an error that could be caused by a misconfigured url route that accepts word characters in the `id` field . (Or it could be something else, but without seeing the traceback we can only guess)

Comment: Added full trace.

Comment: The error is in a misbehaving url route. The view that is dispatched from to the url `/articles/test` expects `/articles/42` or some other numerical id instead of the word `test`. Please include the `urls.py` routes in your question.

Comment: See the end of the post

Comment: you are missing path(<int:pk>/,views.DetailView.as_view(),name="detail" ) in your url,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This route will catch `test`, and route to DetailView. Since `test` is not a number, the result is a `ValueError` exception.

```
path('<pk>',views.DetailView.as_view(),name="detail"),
```

What you want is to only capture numbers here. Django will test each route in order and dispatch the first that matches.

```
path('<pk:int>',views.DetailView.as_view(),name="detail"),
```

Relevant docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters